# how to perform oracle ceil with decimal points

Tags: oracle, rounding, truncate, floor, ceil

In round function we can use (4,512,1) but the same is not true for ceil and floor. I want to ceil and my floor the value 4,512 as 4,5 and 4,6 but the decimal point 1 is not always constant. it may vary. For Floor with decimal points the trunc function can be used. Is there a way to perform ceil with decimal points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting how [the `round` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROUND-number.html) is defined (for positive numbers):

```
ROUND(n, integer) = FLOOR(n * POWER(10, integer) + 0.5) * POWER(10, -integer)
```

... for a general case of a variable ceiling you might want something like:

```
ceil(n * power(10, integer)) * power(10, -integer)
```

So you could define your own functions:

```
create or replace function my_ceil(p_number number, p_decimals pls_integer)
return number as
begin
  return ceil(p_number * power(10, p_decimals)) * power(10, -p_decimals);
end;
/
```

```
create or replace function my_floor(p_number number, p_decimals pls_integer)
return number as
begin
  return floor(p_number * power(10, p_decimals)) * power(10, -p_decimals);
end;
/
```

Then with some sample data:

```
with t (n) as (
  select 4.512 from dual union all
  select 5.12345 from dual union all
  select 6 from dual union all
  select 0 from dual union all
  select -1.23 from dual
)
select n, 0 as d, my_ceil(n, 0) as my_ceil, my_floor(n, 0) as my_floor from t
union all
select n, 1 as d, my_ceil(n, 1), my_floor(n, 1) from t
union all
select n, 2 as d, my_ceil(n, 2), my_floor(n, 2) from t
union all
select n, 3 as d, my_ceil(n, 3), my_floor(n, 3) from t
union all
select n, 4 as d, my_ceil(n, 4), my_floor(n, 4) from t
order by n, d
```

you get:

| N | D | MY_CEIL | MY_FLOOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1.23 | 0 | -1 | -2 |
| -1.23 | 1 | -1.2 | -1.3 |
| -1.23 | 2 | -1.23 | -1.23 |
| -1.23 | 3 | -1.23 | -1.23 |
| -1.23 | 4 | -1.23 | -1.23 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 4.512 | 0 | 5 | 4 |
| 4.512 | 1 | 4.6 | 4.5 |
| 4.512 | 2 | 4.52 | 4.51 |
| 4.512 | 3 | 4.512 | 4.512 |
| 4.512 | 4 | 4.512 | 4.512 |
| 5.12345 | 0 | 6 | 5 |
| 5.12345 | 1 | 5.2 | 5.1 |
| 5.12345 | 2 | 5.13 | 5.12 |
| 5.12345 | 3 | 5.124 | 5.123 |
| 5.12345 | 4 | 5.1235 | 5.1234 |
| 6 | 0 | 6 | 6 |
| 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 |
| 6 | 2 | 6 | 6 |
| 6 | 3 | 6 | 6 |
| 6 | 4 | 6 | 6 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=effab1306404743f2279d74ad553eddb7)

You might need to look at negative values to check they behave as you expect/want, and adjust the functions to mimic `round` if necessary. You also said the decimal might be zero, 1 or more; if that could be negative then it will need more work...

Answer (score 1):

`CEIL` and `FLOOR` return the closest *integer* and don't accept any arguments (but the number itself).

So, if you want to do that up to the 1st decimal, first multiply the number by `10`, `CEIL`/`FLOOR` that value, and then divide it by `10`.

Something like this:

```
SQL> with test (col) as (select 4.521 from dual)
  2  select col,
  3         --
  4         ceil(col * 10) / 10 c_ceil,
  5         floor(col * 10) / 10 c_floor
  6  from test;

       COL     C_CEIL    C_FLOOR
---------- ---------- ----------
     4,521        4,6        4,5

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answert but upto how my decimal is not always fixed it comes through a varibale. it can 0 or 1 or more.